# How do I delete achievements in Fallout Shelter?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I have this one achievement that I can't complete because I don't have the resources to do it. I would like to delete it but I don't know how to.

Comment: Achievements are not the same as objectives, which it appears you're referring to. If you really are referring to Objectives could you please update your post? If you are referring to achievements could you clarify your post further?

Answer (score 4):

If you are referring to the Objectives, you can simply click on the small "x" in the top left hand corner for each entry.

[image]

If you are referring to the actual Achievements, however, this cannot be done. These are the same for everybody, and do not change. They are overall achievements that do not hinder gameplay, and you can choose to work toward them if you wish, or ignore if you choose.

[image]